# SkipList segmentation fault when insert last element

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, void-pointers, skip-lists

I've developed a SkipList with void pointer, and probabilistic way to set the maximum level of it.

those are my structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct _Node{
    Node **next;
    size_t size; //number of pointer in the node
    void *item;
}Node;

typedef struct _SkipList{
    Node **heads;
    size_t max_level; //max height in a single node
    size_t max_height; //max possible height in the skiplist
    int (*compare)(const void *, const void *);
}SkipList;

double random_probability() {
    return (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

size_t random_level(size_t max_height) {
    size_t level = 1;
    while (random_probability() < 0.5 && level < max_height) {
        level++;
    }
    return level;
}

Node *create_node(void *item, size_t level) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!newNode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione del nodo.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->size = level;
    newNode->next = (Node **)malloc(level * sizeof(Node *));
    if (!newNode->next) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione dei puntatori successivi.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        newNode->next[i] = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}

void new_skiplist(SkipList **list, size_t max_height, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *)) {
    *list = (SkipList *)malloc(sizeof(SkipList));
    if (!*list) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione della SkipList.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*list)->heads = (Node **)calloc(max_height, sizeof(Node *));
    if (!(*list)->heads) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione dei puntatori iniziali.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*list)->max_level = 0;
    (*list)->max_height = max_height;
    (*list)->compare = compare;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
}
```

and this are the insert function

```
void insert_skiplist(SkipList *list, void *item) {
    Node **update = (Node **)malloc((list->max_height + 1) * sizeof(Node *));
    if (!update) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione dell'array di aggiornamento.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Node *x = list->heads;

    // loop invariant: x[i]->item <= item or item < first element of level i in list
    for (size_t i = list->max_level; i > 0; i--) {
        while (x->next[i - 1] != NULL && list->compare(x->next[i - 1]->item, item) <= 0) {
            x = x->next[i - 1];
        }
        update[i] = x;
    }

    // loop end: x[1]->item <= item or item < first element in list
    x = x->next[0];

    if (x != NULL && list->compare(x->item, item) == 0) {
        // Elemento già presente, aggiorna il valore o gestisci il caso a tuo piacimento
        // x->item = newValue;
        free(update);
        return;
    }

    size_t level = random_level(list->max_height);

    if (level > list->max_level) {
        for (size_t i = list->max_level + 1; i <= level; i++) {
            update[i] = list->heads;
        }
        list->max_level = level;
    }

    x = create_node(item, level);

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
        x->next[i - 1] = update[i]->next[i - 1];
        update[i]->next[i - 1] = x;
    }

    free(update);
}
    const void *search_skiplist(SkipList *list, void *item) {
        Node **x = list->heads;
        for (size_t i = list->max_level; i > 0; i--) {
            while (x[i] != NULL && list->compare(x[i]->item, item) < 0) {
                x = x[i]->next;
            }
        }

        if (x[1] != NULL && list->compare(x[1]->item, item) == 0) {
            return x[1]->item;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

now, when i try to create a skiplist from the array on the main:

```
int compare_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
 int x = (int *)a;
 int y = (int *)b;
 return (x - y);
}
int main() {
 srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

 SkipList *int_list;
 new_skiplist(&int_list, 10, compare_int);

 int int_keys[] = {3, 6, 1, 8, 2, 7, 5, 4, 9};
 for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int_keys) / sizeof(int_keys[0]); i++) {
     insert_skiplist(int_list, int_keys[i]);
 }
const void* found=search_skiplist(int_list,9);
 if(found!=NULL) printf("FOUNDED\n");
 clear_skiplist(int_list);
return 0;
```

all goes ok, untill i try to insert 8, the problem seems that if my insert have to put a node at the end of the list, it get segmentation fault.

precisely, GDB get this error when i try to insert 8 item:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
Inser into  SkipList int: 9

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004017ff in insert_skiplist (list=0xad1800, item=0x3) at src/skiplist.c:104
104         x = x->next[0];
(gdb) bt
#0  0x004017ff in insert_skiplist (list=0xad1800, item=0x3) at src/skiplist.c:104
#1  0x00401af6 in main () at src/main_ex2.c:30
(gdb) print (int)item
$1 = 3
(gdb) print (int*)item
$2 = (int *) 0x3
(gdb) print (int)x->item
$3 = 0
(gdb) print x->item
$4 = (void *) 0x0
(gdb) print x->next[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb)
(gdb)
```

so it cannot access to the previous item in the k-1 node, and i d'ont understand why because it put the 6 after 3 and 1 without error.

I'm stucked with this error, can someone help me to understand the bug?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You need to show the code that creates the list. The problem might be there. We need a [mcve]. Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Big props for using a debugger to try to narrow it down. We don't see nearly enough of that.

Comment: @Trammy please show a [mcve] (something that can be copy/pasted/compiled), not bits of code that need to be stiched together. Also show the input if any.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ther is all the code, no input, just copy the main, and put in the same file the structs and all the method, remember to include the library in the main

Comment: Some things my IDE complains about: `int x = (int *)a;` -- incompatible conversion.  `search_skiplist(int_list, 9);` -- incompatible conversion (second argument). `insert_skiplist(int_list, int_keys[i]);` -- incompatible conversion (second argument). Mixing pointers to ints and ints seems a bad idea.

Comment: if you cast a pointer of a voi as ani int, it work, the proof is that the GDB debugger recognise it as an int after casting, and inserting 1,3,and 6 work so the comparison function i think is not the problem

Comment: @Jabberwocky had you chance to compile my code?

Comment: Your code does not compile. I had to change `Node** next;` to `struct _Node** next;`. With that it compiles, but it's full of warnings. Look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6rrrx693f). [Edit] your question and post your **verbatim code**. Post a [mcve]. But anyway, all those warning are actually errors. Fix them, otherwise there is no chance this will ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the adressing, this passage is wrong

```
Node *x = list->heads;
```

it must be

```
Node *x = &list->heads.
```

now all work fine